# Spring Boot 3.1.0: Spring Security is not allowing POST call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Trying to implement Spring security with

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}
```

have dependency of

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
```

created some test end point like -

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/open")
public class OpenedController {

    @GetMapping
    public String secureHi() {
        log.info("Hi, I am opened.");
        return "Hi, I am opened.";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String secureHPost(@RequestBody MyUser myUser) {
        log.info("Hi, I am opened POST. myUser ={}", myUser);
        return "Hi, I am opened POST.";
    }
}
```

and my configuration file is as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {

    UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("chitta")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("chitta"))
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();

    UserDetails user = User.withUsername("aaa")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("aa"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
            (authorize) -> authorize
                    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/open**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().denyAll()
    );

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

when I am trying to access the **POST** method, I am getting

```
{
"timestamp": "2023-06-16T08:50:43.240+00:00",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"path": "/open"
}
```

but the **GET method is accessibly** and working fine.
Could not find out - What I am missing?

I also have tried with `.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/open**").permitAll()` but this is also not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable csrf, by default in spring this one is active:

```
http
    // ...
    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please debug your `CsrfFilter.java` file in Spring-Security.
In the default case, Spring will check the `csrfToken` in the header during a POST request.

If you don't want to send the `csrfToken`, please make the CSRF filter disabled, just like @Andrei Lisa suggested.